# How to get $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{2}$ from $a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n + a_{n+1}}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

How does one get the below?  Can someone break this down for me?

Given:

$$
a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n + a_{n+1}}{2},
$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$

How do you get:

$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{2}$$

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**: $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2} - a_{n+1}=...$

Comment: Thank you i appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

This relationship can as well be established through a geometric representation, i.e., the $(n+2)$nd term is the middle between the $(n+1)$st and the $n$th.

Thus the distance between two consecutive terms is halved at each new step.

$$\tag{1}|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|=\frac12 |a_{n+1} - a_{n}|$$

Besides, there is a sign switch at each step (for example, if $a_{n+1}>a_n$ at a step, then their midpoint $a_{n+2}$ will be less than $a_{n+1}$ at the next step). Thus (1) gives the result:

$$\tag{2} a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}= \ - \ \frac12 (a_{n+1} - a_{n})$$

Remark: this is by no means a shorter proof. I just advocate such a geometrical approach as fruitful as initial (guessing) and final (checking).

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely basic and you definitely need to work on your manipulation!

$$a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}-2a_{n+1}}{2}=\frac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{2}$$

I provided the full working here as it appears that you are struggling - but this is usually a single step, since the algebraic manipulation is so trivial.

Please up vote or accept this answer if you are satisfied!